# "Hide Top Bar" GNOME Shell extension makes top bar cover desktop icons

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Similar to how [auto-hiding the dock makes it cover desktop icons](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066420/auto-hiding-the-dock-covers-the-desktop-icons), Hide Top Bar, which auto-hides the top bar, makes it so it covers desktop icons.
[image: Screenshot of top bar covering desktop icon]

I would like the icons to default to positions not covered by the top bar. I've also noticed it moves the dock slightly upward, which I don't mind. How can I fix this?

I added an issue to it's GitHub page: [here's the issue](https://github.com/mlutfy/hidetopbar/issues/190).

Comment: Apparently someone has a solution there: https://github.com/mlutfy/hidetopbar/issues/190#issuecomment-560157437 but I don know how to implement it... I'd be grateful is someone explains it!