# Hiding taskbar and topbar in Ubuntu 19.04

Tags: 19.04, gnome-shell, gui, ubuntu-dock, autohide

I'd like to have both the taskbar (Ubuntu Dock) and the topbar auto-hidden in Ubuntu 19.04. I've tried a number of extensions but they're not doing exactly that - mostly they hide then when a window or the cursor hovers over these regions.

Is there a way to have them auto-hidden so that only desktop icons show when I'm in the desktop view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To keep the Ubuntu Dock hidden until mouse-hover, run the following command in Terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock intellihide false
```

(reference: [Ubuntu dock is stuck](https://askubuntu.com/q/1034517/480481))

For the top bar, you may use a [GNOME Shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/q/75530/480481) called [**Hide Top Bar**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/). You need to turn the intellihide features **off** from the extension's settings window:
[image]

Comment: Exactly what I needed!

Comment: Autohide Topbar: For Ubuntu 20.04, `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-autohidetopbar`, installs `gnome-tweaks` among other dependencies. Requires Restart. Tweaks -> Extension -> Hide top bar